# How to interact from Office VBA with a Libre Sheet

Tags: vba, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

How do I get as Object the LibreOfficeCalcPortable.exe to interact from Catia VBA. I write bellow the way to interact with MS Excel from Catia VBA. how to write within a Cell from LibreOfficeCalcPortable.exe from CATIA VBA?

Example Catia to Excel.

```
Dim Excel As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set Excel = GetObject(, "EXCEL.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
```

Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think that this is possible at all? Did you find something in Catia's documentation? What did your web research reveal concerning LibreOffice and VBA?

Comment: Are you familiar with the language used by LibreOffice/OpenOffice? The way of automate it is completely different. Please, look [here](https://www.openoffice.org/udk/common/man/tutorial/office_automation.html) to see examples. They are basically focused on VBScript, but deleting `Wscript.` from the start, the code can be used as it is in a VBA environment. It will create a Writer document and do something in it. At the end, it is a link to `WriterDemo.vbs`, which will open the script code. It can be copied in VBA, follow my suggested before and add another argument to `createStruct` function.

Comment: The code is designed for OpenOffice. I only heard about the fact that it is similar to LibreOffice... I made some automations in OpenOffice some years before, but never in LibreOffice.

Comment: Is the restriction of using Libre Office instead of Excel related to the fact that it is a free application? If yes, I had a similar request from a kind of customer and I've chosen OpenOffice. If this is the case a can post a piece of code checking if OpenOffice is installed, opening a '.ods' file in its 'calc' application and save it as '.csv' comma delimited. I have another one extracting an array from the `ods' file range. I created an application for Cored, which needed more ways of inputs (barcodes, xls files, ods files, txt files etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Calc example in VBScript which I tested just now in LibreOffice 7.2. See the comment by @FaneDuru regarding how to adapt for VBA.

```
Set oSM = CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
Set oDesk = oSM.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
Dim arg()
Set wb = oDesk.loadComponentFromURL("private:factory/scalc", "_blank", 0, arg)
Set oSheet = wb.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
oSheet.getCellByPosition(1, 2).String = "Hello world!"
MsgBox "The End"
```